Use TomTom Data as Network Dataset to Calculate OD Cost Matrix Distance and Time
I am stuck in with configuring a network dataset using TomTom data. I used to rely on the Routing_ND network dataset provided by ESRI Business Analyst to perform OD Cost Matrix analysis. Now I am thinking about replacing this Routing_ND dataset with the TomTom nam2024_03_000-shpd-mn-usa-uwi -> nw layer to create and configure a new network dataset.
I tried to create, configure, and build a network dataset based on TomTom data, and then ran the Cost OD Matrix analysis based on a sample of 5 office locations and 5 employees in Wisconsin. However, the result based on TomTom data looks different compared to the results generated from ESRI and Google Map. The miles are fairly close, but looks like the employee would take more time to drive from home to the office based on TomTom data calculations. See the below screenshot.

I compared the network dataset properties between TomTom network dataset and Esri BA Routing_ND dataset. I find that there are more feature classes along with the Routing_ND network dataset in ESRI's geodatabase (left is my data, right is ESRI data). Do not know if this difference would affect the miles and minutes calculations that much.

In addition, because I used "Create Network Dataset" tool to create this WI_ND network layer, so the "Traffic" section in the properties is not supported. But Esri Routing_ND dataset has the "Traffic" section configured. Do not know if this difference would affect the miles and minutes calculations that much.

The attributes in TomTom network dataset are different from the attributes in ESRI Routing_ND as well. For example, I could not find an equivalent of this "FT/TF_RST_AUTOMOBILES" attribute from ESRI routing_ND dataset in TomTom data because I need it as an active restriction (prohibit an automobile) when I perform OD Cost Matrix analysis. The screenshot below shows the settings in ESRI routing_ND dataset.

My goal is to make the distance and time calculated based on TomTom data close to the results from Esri (and Google Maps). I just do not know which network property is necessary to configure, or maybe I need more data?

I believe there are more details in TomTom data including the speed profiles and more restrictive details - see https://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc15/papers/173_467.pdf (if you remove speed profiles does your distances change?)
